# Awk/Sed to replace word after specific string

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file like below

```
<DATABASE name="ABC" url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:eqprod3:5060/ABC01" driver="com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver" user="user" pwd="password" minConnections="10" maxConnections="10" maxConnectionLife="1440000" startDate="01/01/2014" endDate="01/30/2014" type="dev"/>

<DATABASE name="XYZ" url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:eqprod2:5050/XYZ01" driver="com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver" user="user" pwd="password" minConnections="10" maxConnections="10" maxConnectionLife="1440000" startDate="02/01/2014" endDate="02/02/2014" type="dev"/>
```

Now I want to search for word `ABC01` in url part and search next `startDate` to it and change the value, lets say to `02/01/2014`.

Could you please help me to get required output.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` :

```
sed '/ABC01/ s/startDate="[^"]*"/startDate="02\/01\/2014"/g' your.file
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But somehow its not working :( Can you please check?

Comment: `sed '/ABC01/ s|startDate="[^"]*"|startDate="02/01/2014"|g' YourFile` for better reading of separator and maybe use `-e` option

Comment: @NeronLeVelu why `-e`?

Comment: Hi .. Second part works perfectly.. but First part doesn't work. I mean sed '/ABC01/ Using second part it replaces all the startDate where I want against condition as search ABC01.

Comment: Here every entry is on different line. First part works when I have complete tag on one line.

Comment: Multiline sed expression are getting too messy in this case. I highly encourage you to use a DOMParser and/or XSLT

Comment: @hek2mgl for forcing the next string as Expression script (reduce RegEx) in this case `-r` seems no better (for extended Regular expression)

Answer (score 0):

This script works for both single- and multi-line `DATABASE` elements.

```
awk '
# search for ABC01 in url attribute
/url="[^"]*ABC01[^"]*"/{
  # set the flag
  f = 1;
  # current line number
  i1 = NR;
}
# save line if the flag is set
(f){lines[NR] = $0}
# output line otherwise
(!f){print $0}
# if the flag is set, search for startDate attribute
(f && $0 ~ /startDate="/){
  # replace value of startDate attribute with 02/01/2014
  s = gensub(/(startDate=")[^"]+/, "\\102/01/2014", 1, $0)
  # current line number
  i2 = NR;
  # output non-modified lines (no output if i2 == i1)
  for (i = i1; i < i2; i++){print lines[i]};
  # output modified line
  print s;
  # unset the flag
  f = 0;
}'
```